Are the Kinmen Islands visible from Xiamen?
The Kinmen Islands, administered by the Republic of China (Taiwan), are only a few km away from the major Chinese city of Xiamen. The skyscrapers of Xiamen are clearly visible from Kinmen, but is the reverse also true, since the Kinmen Islands are much more low-rise?  If yes, where in Xiamen should I go to get the best view?
Complication: I'll be visiting in January, which is historically one of the worst months for air pollution (average AQI around 100).
Also, I'm aware there are ferries between the two, but I have very limited time so actually visiting will, sadly, not be an option this time.

From where exactly?  If you can see the skyscrapers from Kinmen, then presumably you can see Kinmen from the skyscrapers?

@Doc That's what I'm asking, just because there's a skyscraper doesn't mean it's open to the public.

I have seen the map link - I had no idea where these islands were located - and now I am curious. It appears the islands are only a few km offshore, therefore I am wondering why did you think they were not visible?

@VladimirCravero I've been to Beijing in winter when there's so much smog you can't see across the street, never mind a few km away.

This is so surprising for me - thanks. I live in Tuscany, in Italy, and on good days I can see mountains/islands that are ~100 km away.

They are easily visible. In Xiamen you can walk down to the water, there is some kind of promenade and unless it is super foggy you can see the islands. Source, I've been there and done that.

Visible on Google Maps: https://maps.app.goo.gl/97zJMF436hJTKojk6?g_st=ic
